# What are 36 kinds of weapons & tactics of the war?

Tags: shiva, dharma, weapon, war

In Shiv Rahasya on 11th chapters Lord Shiva giving commandments to Kaliyuga people. Here is characteristics of a King.

> The King shall favour peace above war. He shall not start a war without just cause. But if
>   assailed by the enemy, he shall be fearless in defending himself and his realm. He shall be skilled
>   in the use of the **thirty-six kinds of weapons and in tactics of war**. He shall
>   enter the battlefield like an elephant entering a lotus pond. He shall be brave in battle,
>   magnanimous in victory and unbowed in defeat. 11.58

I want to know what are those 36 kinds of weapons & tactics of war?

Comment: tactics of war refer to yuddhanīti. As for 36 weapons, check this out https://www.wisdomlib.org/jainism/book/trishashti-shalaka-purusha-caritra/d/doc212415.html There are a few Jaina lists, which mention 36 weapons.